# how to get only withCount attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a situation where I only need to return the withCount attribute

for example, I have

```php
$data = SystemReport::withCount(['unit' => function($query)  {
                $query->where('totalPercentage', '=', 100);

        }])->get()
        ->groupBy(function($val) {
                return Carbon::parse($val->updated_at)->format('M');
        });
```

that returns

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "unit_id": 1,
    "human_resource_id": null,
    "quality_id": null,
    "construction_id": 1,
    "digital_transformation_id": 1,
    "confirmationDate": "2024-11-10",
    "expectedDate": "2024-11-20",
    "totalPercentage": 90,
    "created_at": "2021-05-29T11:44:25.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-29T16:22:10.000000Z",
    "unit_count": 0
},
```

I want to return only the `unit_count` which is the attribute that has been added by withCount

**NOTE**

I don't want to map over it after getting the result, I wish if there a solution in laravel eloquent itself

So does anyone knows how?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pluck to get only `unit count`.For mapping count i have used key as id .

```
$data = SystemReport::withCount(['unit' => function($query)  {
                $query->where('totalPercentage', '=', 100);

        }])->pluck("unit_count","id");
```

**Updated**

```
 $data = SystemReport::withCount(['unit' => function($query)  {
        $query->where('totalPercentage', '=', 100);

    }])->get()
        ->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->updated_at)->format('M');
        }) ->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->pluck("unit_count","id"); 
        });
```

Comment: Yes, It works for the code the situation I posted but for not the actual code! 
 I'm sorry I didn't think it would affect anything. I have updated my question so if you may give another look, I would appreciate it

Comment: @omaresmaeel.glad to here ,you have solved your issue